# CRM email not appearing in queues

Tags: email, exchange-server, dynamics-crm

I have a CRM applicaton with queues setup to receive emails. It is all working as expected except for one exception.

The client is scanning letters that they receive and using a SMTP request via their exchange server to send the scanned letter to the queue in an email message. The message is being delivered to the email address but it is not going into the queue in CRM.

Relaying has been enabled on the exchange server for the CRM system. If the message is sent from a normal email address it enters the queue as expected. There is nothing in the Trace logs or the event viewer on the CRM server to indicate why the message is not going into the queue.

Can anybody provide me with some suggestions as to why this could be happening?

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Make sure that the eMails are sent to the exact same address that is set for the queue in CRM. It is not enough to have them delivered into the right mailbox by Exchange; the eMail Router will only transfer them into the queue if the recipient address is identical.

Comment: Okay Im getting this error message: #6511 - An error occurred while checking the e-mail message with subject "test 1 SMTP 25102010" in mailbox cmscomplaintstest@rsa.ie for delivery to ... System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request.
\r\n
  0x80040b08
  The sender does not have an email address on the party record
  Platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the mails weren't entering the mailbox at all